# c# dynamically created controls: how to do event handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, dynamic-controls

First: i have seen here on stack overflow a lot of answers, related to my topic, but i dont understand the answers, cause im new to c#, asp.net and web application developement. So i think its better, if I explain my problem here in detail. Pls note, that im really a newbie to web developement, so i really need details.

My Task (the problem):
I have created in one of the methods of my codebehind file a table, to show users and for every user a checkbox. 
user1 checkbox
user2 checkbox
user3 checkbox
...
The goal is, that the application should provide excluding this users from some further action. 
Here is the codesnippet, where the table is created:

```
TableRow trHead = new TableRow(); 
TableCell tcNameHead = new TableCell();
//Header of the first column of the Table
tcNameHead.Text = "Users to be deleted";
tcNameHead.CssClass = "headerResultsRowForProject";
trHead.Cells.Add(tcNameHead);
//Here is de first entry of the 'exclude_from_delete' column
TableCell tcGroupHead = new TableCell();
tcGroupHead.Text = "exclude from delete";
tcGroupHead.CssClass = "headerResultsRow";
trHead.Cells.Add(tcGroupHead);
TableBert.Rows.Add(trHead);

foreach (ListItem li in list_deletedUsers.Items)
{
    String s = li.Text;
    //Creating the basic Elements
    TableRow myrow = new TableRow();
    TableCell cellone = new TableCell();
    TableCell celltwo = new TableCell();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    //cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;
    //cb.CheckedChanged += this.cb_CheckedChanged; /*does not work!*/
    //cb.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged); /*does not work!*/
    //Setting the values and adding cells to row
    cellone.Text = s;
    myrow.Cells.Add(cellone);
    celltwo.Controls.Add(cb);
    celltwo.ApplyStyle(tableStyle);
    myrow.Cells.Add(celltwo);
    //Third Column Cell for further use
    //TableCell cellthree = new TableCell();
    //cellthree.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
    //Adding to Row
    //myrow.Cells.Add(cellthree);
    //Adding to TableBert
    TableBert.Rows.Add(myrow);
}
```

The table is displayed (and bevore: created), every time, i choose the appopriate radio button on the website.

But now i have problems with the eventhandling: i have to check, which of the checkboxes is marked and remove the corresponding user from a special list (so this user will not be part of the following process).

i have written code for the event handling, here is the snippet:

```
protected void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do sth.
    }
```

but this method is never invoced. I didnt really understand, but i googled the whole day. As far as i have understood: it has to do with the page lifecycle and that i raise a postback event by clicking on the checkbox? Like u see, im not shure. I have also read, that one should "create the dynamic controls in the page_load method". But i dont have my checkboxes, if i got to the pageload method, or at least, i dond have any idea, how to handle that. I would appreciate any idea, any explanation. If u can support me with some good pages, that will help me learn this (and other topics) by myself, it really would help me. :)

Note: i allready was on some microsoft pages and here on stackoverflow and on other pages, where this topic is discussed. But i think, i would need someone, who explains in detail, whats going on here and how i can do event handling, step by step and with background. Or support me with an internet source, that explains all i should know. Pls dont forget: im totally new ;)

Comment: When you say "does not work" in the code above, are you saying nothing happens or you have an error?

Comment: Hi, ok, "does not work" means, that nothing happens. I was ruuning the debugger in vs 2015 and i never reach the code, i wrote for event handling. As far as i have read in other articles here in the internet: it has to do with the lifecycle of a page.